# Filter Loop by Custom Field Value

Tags: query-posts, loop, meta-query

I'm trying to filter a loop by a custom field value.  I've tried all of the suggestions on the site, but it just won't filter. This loop is being used for a custom template of an rss feed. It pulls together the custom post type and only the posts that are "published", but I can't get it to filter by custom field value.

`global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'custom_type', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'meta_key' => 'my_custom_field', 'meta_value' => 'custom field value',  ) );
query_posts( $args );
?>`

while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                'post_type'=> 'custom_type',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'meta_key' => 'my_custom_field',
                                'meta_value' => 'custom field value'
                              ));

if($my_query->have_posts()):
    while($my_query->have_posts()):$my_query->the_post();
        //All the post stuff here.
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Check this out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The loop works fine with the post type and post status, it just doesn't filter the loop by meta key and meta value.

Comment: Update.. I was able to make work by adding a comma at the end of meta_value line...  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked! You're welcome! But I don't understand how that associative array worked with a 'comma' after the last key-value pair, that's not supposed to happen! Not an issue though!